# Why doesnt UIScrollView zoom when i click on it?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

1. I subclassed UIScrollView
2. Then created an object of it in the main class.
3. Added an image to it.
4. Set the zoomscales  as

   ```
   scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
   scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 4.00;
   ```

After all this

Q. Is it supposed to zoom out when I double-tap on it and also support pinch zoom?

Q. Shouldn't I do it programmatically?

Q. Does UIImageView or someother class support this behavious by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView will not zoom unless you set the `maximumZoomScale` and/or `minimumZoomScale`.

And return the image in `-viewForZoomingInScrollView:` in your delegate. And implement `-scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`.

See http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8453852#8453852 for detail.